# Stirling Series Derivation from Saddle-Point/Method of Steepest descent

Tags: integration, gamma-function

I'm trying to derive the Stirling Series from the gamma function

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
    \Gamma (N+1) &= \int_0^\infty x^N e^{-x} dx \\
    &= \int_0^\infty e^{N (\ln x - \frac{x}{N})} dx \\
\end{split}
\end{equation}

Thus the $\phi(x)$ for the saddle point approximation here is $\ln{x} - \frac{x}{N}$. Expanding this around it's maximum at $x_{max} = N$

\begin{equation}
    \begin{split}
    \phi(x) &\approx \ln{N}-1 + \phi'(x_{max}) + \frac{1}{2!}\left(\frac{-1}{N^2}\right)\left(x-N\right)^2 + \frac{1}{3!} \left( \frac{2}{N^3} \right) \left(x-N\right)^3 - \frac{6}{4!N^4} (x-N)^4 + \frac{24}{5! N^3} (x-N)^5 + ...\\
    &\approx \ln{N}-1 - \frac{1}{2N^2}\left(x-N\right)^2 + \frac{1}{3N^3}  \left(x-N\right)^3 - \frac{1}{4N^4} (x-N)^4 + \frac{1}{5N^3} (x-N)^5 + ...\\
    \end{split}
\end{equation}

Back to the gamma function

\begin{equation}
    \begin{split}
    \Gamma (N+1) &= \int_0^\infty e^{N (\ln N - \frac{x}{N})} dx \\
    &= \int_0^\infty exp \left(N\left(\ln{N}-1 - \frac{1}{2N^2}\left(x-N\right)^2 + \frac{1}{3N^3}  \left(x-N\right)^3 - \frac{1}{4N^4} (x-N)^4 + \frac{1}{5N^3} (x-N)^5 + ... \right)\right)  dx \\ \\
    &= \left( \frac{N}{e} \right)^N \int_0^\infty exp \left(- \frac{1}{2N}\left(x-N\right)^2 + \frac{1}{3N^2}  \left(x-N\right)^3 - \frac{1}{4N^3} (x-N)^4 + \frac{1}{5N^4} (x-N)^5 + ... \right)  dx \\
    &= \left( \frac{N}{e} \right)^N \int_0^\infty \prod_{n=0}^\infty e^{\:\frac{(-1)^n}{nN^{n-1}} (x-N)^n} dx \\
    \end{split}
\end{equation}

I am lost as to how to proceed from here.  Maybe expanding all of the exponentials? I have a few other ideas, but as to not clutter I'll leave it there.

Comment: Do you mean to have a $\ln x$ in your exponential rather than a $\ln N$?  Note that your $\phi$ should not depend on the large parameter ($N$) in applying these methods. you might have to do some substitution to remove it.

Comment: Sorry, there was a typo with the ln(N) in the gamma function. I am following this from some inspiration from

http://home.ustc.edu.cn/~hyx/ref/Mehran%20Kardar-Statistical%20Physics%20of%20Particles%20(2007).pdf

top of page 50, if that helps.

Comment: Use \exp to produce $\exp$. After using the series expansion, you don't have an equality anymore because the series does not converge for all $x>0$. Things become easier if you substitute $x=N e^t$ at the very beginning and consider the $t$-integral.